# How can i define Custom exception class in laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have tried to define custom exception class in Laravel 5.3.But i couldn't find any solution.

How can i define and call custom exception class inside API controller in Laravel 5.3.Any help would be much appreciated..

Answer (score 3):

Write a new CustomException class and extends the \Exception class:

```
CustomException extends \Exception {}
```

to use your custom exception class this is an example of use in controller:

```
public function someAction() {
  throw new CustomException('your message error')
   // or
  try {
  } catch (Exception $e) {
     throw new CustomException($e->getMessage());
     // ...
  }
}
```